# Prevent Firefox from downloading shockwave (.swf) files

Tags: flash, shockwave

I have Firefox 60.8.0esr (64-bit) and I have installed Adobe Flash Player.

I can test I got it in here: https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player.html and I see I got the 32.0.0.238 version.

Then, inside Firefox -> Addons -> Plugins -> Shockwave -> Preferences I have the "Block Dangerous and intrusive Flash Content", nonethless, when I go to an URL with a .swf file, it tries to download it instead of loading it.

Answer (score 0):

> *"When I go to an URL with a `.swf` file, it tries to download it instead of displaying it."*

Firefox / Chrome / Edge all expect the `.swf` file to be **embedded** in an HTML document.

To have a display instead of a download, put code like example below into an HTML file then load the HTML file's url in browser address (because a direct SWF url will **not** work).

Code for some example `showFlash.html`:

```
<div id="flash">
<embed src="yourfile.swf" 
width="800" height="600" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
quality="high" wmode="transparent" scale="noscale"
</embed>
```

Comment: PS: Make sure Flash is **enabled** and not blocked in anyway (via Options).